# Is there a bug with the "Dedicated to Crimson" Achievement?

Tags: achievements, halo-4

I know I am a little behind the ball, but I just recently completed all chapters in the first 5 episodes of Spartan Ops.  I believe this entitles me to the "Dedicated to Crimson" Achievement.

> Dedicated to Crimson
>
> Completed all chapters in the first 5 episodes of Spartan Ops on any difficulty.

I can look in the "Play Chapters" menu and see that all chapters are completed at Heroic or better (most via matchmaking).  Why have I not received the achievement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently this is a [known issue](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/8/p/404312/2044743.aspx#2044743) although 343 has yet to add it to their [known issues thread on Waypoint](https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_postst130475_Issues-being-investigated.aspx).

Luckily, the fix is pretty easy.  Apparently, the problem is that the achievement will not trigger in matchmade Spartan Ops.  Start a Spartan Op solo, even on easy difficulty, and you should get the achievement after completing the Op.  I recommend Episode 1 Chapter 1, as that worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, I did this last night and it worked for me.  I was pretty bummed when I didn't get it the other day after finishing all of them :(